# calling a function inside a class from another class php

Tags: php, oop

I am very new to oops in php. Can anyone tell me how can i use a function

```
    public static function getCategories($id_lang = false, $active = true,$order = true, $sql_filter = '', $sql_sort = '', $sql_limit = '')
            {
             if (!Validate::isBool($active))
             die(Tools::displayError());
             $result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS('
              SELECT *
              FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'category` c
              ' . Shop::addSqlAssociation('category', 'c') . '
              LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'category_lang` cl ON c.`id_category` = cl.`id_category`' . Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('cl') . '
              WHERE 1 ' . $sql_filter . ' ' . ($id_lang ? 'AND `id_lang` = ' . (int)$id_lang : '') . '
              ' . ($active ? 'AND `active` = 1' : '') . '
             ' . (!$id_lang ? 'GROUP BY c.id_category' : '') . '
              ' . ($sql_sort != '' ? $sql_sort : 'ORDER BY c.`level_depth` ASC, category_shop.`position` ASC') . '
            ' . ($sql_limit != '' ? $sql_limit : '')
                      );

                if (!$order)
                   return $result;

                   $categories = array();
                   foreach ($result as $row)
                   $categories[$row['id_parent']][$row['id_category']]['infos'] = $row;

               return $categories;
              }
```

`getCategories()` is inside a class named **class CategoryCore** i want to use this `getcategory` into a new class **totalDiscount** in which a function called `configure_products();`

How can i use `getcategory()` inside the configure products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include the class file on the page

You can create a object of the class inside another class

```
function configure_products(){
    $categories = new CategoryCore();
    $categories->getcategory();
   // use $categories to do stuff 
     ......
     .....
}
```

### OR

You can call it directly

```
function configure_products(){
     $categories =   CategoryCore::getCategories();
     .....
     ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `getCategories()` is a static function.

So, it can be called without creating object on teh class `CategoryCore`.

You can use it as (using scope resolution operator):

`$categories = CategoryCore::getCategories(YOUR_ARGUMENTS)`

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.forward-static-call.php)

Comment: yes but how can i access the $categories inside product_configure()?